# Fail to ssh to server with Putty only, but successfully using git bash ssh

Tags: ssh, putty

I am facing a weird issue when I ssh to my Ubuntu with Putty. When I ssh to my Ubuntu, the only thing I got is a blank screen, and no connection failure. However, when I use ssh in Git bash, it works.

I have already checked all common troubleshooting issue

1. OpenSSH is installed and sshd is up on running,
2. Port is listening checked by `netstat`
3. Firewall disabled

For the environment, the Ubuntu is installed in virtualbox, using NAT interface and setting up port forwarding already.

So, what are other possible issue?

Comment: what do you see in putty log, when you activate it?

Comment: Since it is too long, please refer to here: http://textuploader.com/577wh. Basically after startup and transferring those packets, it has stopped and the screen stays blank.

Comment: *"Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange"* ... first guess, are you using up-to-date verison of PuTTY? Can you try to install current version?

Comment: wow ! Your first guess is actually the answer. Never thought of that. Thank you. Can you write the answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have up-to-date PuTTY. You know, windows does not have any centralized way of updates so one can simply end up using something broken. Version signature shows some quite old date.